# placeholder in directory  - printf in awk 

Tags: linux, shell, awk, printf, placeholder

i am doing this:

```
lastnames="test"
mode="04"
print $0 >> sprintf("%s\/%s_file_%s.txt",lastnames,lastnames,mode);
```

it says: `` fatal: can't redirect to `/_file_04.txt' (Permission denied) ``

but if i do this:

```
lastnames="test"
mode="04"
print $0 >> sprintf("test/%s_file_%s.txt",lastnames,mode);
```

it is working. why is this? am i doing something wrong, or is there special cases in replacing directory names? or do i have to escape `%s/%s`,

i will apppreciate any help.. thanks a lot

Comment: Typo in variable name `lastname` vs. `lastnames`.  Fix the question or delete it.

Comment: That's better, but you kept the original error message. Try this again, and report the results.

Comment: error message is still the same not depending on the ``lastnames``, it was just typo in posting into stackoverflow.

Comment: In that case, split the print into `file=sprintf("test/%s_file_%s.txt",lastnames,mode);` and `print "file=" file;` followed by `print >> file`

Comment: sir, i am trying to avoid exactly this. i want that the ``test`` should be dynamic.. anyway, problem solved

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Check that there is no typo between variable declaration (`lastname`) and usage (`lastnames`) and that the directory exists, because `awk` won't create it.

One workaround could be to avoid the `sprintf`, like this:

```
awk ' {
    lastname="test"
    mode="04"
    print $0 >> lastname "/" lastname "_file_" mode ".txt"
} 
' infile
```

Comment: oh yeah, it was only here typo, in my code it is ``lastnames`` and the folder exists already..but it is still not working for me :(

Comment: ``%s/%s`` is this rendered well?

Comment: @doniyor: Yes. I tested both and work fine. The `\/` version gives me the following warning: **escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'**, but it does the job too.

Comment: your version is also not working.. isnot the ``Permission denied`` the key for problem? the file is created in this folder but nothing is written there.

Comment: I don't think so. If you can create the file, you will be able to write it. Your code is not complete (I had to add curly braces). Paste a small working version that I can test and check what the problem is.

Comment: here is the code: http://pastebin.com/d9LbhV7V
note: the folder ``lastnames`` with some name in ``USER.TXT`` already exists

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being dumb, i was looping several times over the same thing and splitting so many times as a loop, then as a result this is happening:

```
split(name, lastnames, "") => [first, second]
```

then second loop doesnot have `name` string since it has been already splitted.. as a result, i was referring to something like this: `/file.txt` because the folder name before the `/` was empty..

thanks for your views anyway..